# How to crop Geotiff image in C++ (GDAL or other possibilities)?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, c++, clip

I am developing a code to process a geotiff image. But firsly I need to crop a geotiff image preserving its metadata (projection...) in C++. My idea it's to provide the corners and the geotiff image to a function inside the code and then it return the subset. I thought about using GDAL but I don´t know if there is any code or function.

Anybody know about this?

Comment: you should look at vrt first, a simple xml file that can be used to create a virtual subset of your data. http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html

Answer (score 3):

You could do this easily enough in C++. The way I would do it is to send the path of the file you want to crop, the path of the output/cropped raster, the top left coordinates of the cropped raster and the width and height of the cropped raster. An outline for your code could look something like this. . .

```cpp
void crop(const char *inputPath, const char *cropPath, double topLeftX, double topLeftY,
          double width, double height)
{
    GDALDataset *pInputRaster, *pCroppedRaster;
    GDALDriver *pDriver;
    pDriver = GDALGetDriverManager->getDriverByName("Name of you driver here");

    pInputRaster = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(inputPath, GA_ReadOnly);

    //the affine transformation information, you will need to adjust this to properly
    //display the clipped raster
    double transform[6];
    pInputRaster->getGeoTransform(transform);

    //adjust top left coordinates
    transform[0] = topLeftX;
    transform[3] = topLeftY;

    //determine dimensions of the new (cropped) raster in cells
    int xSize = round(width/transform[1]);
    int ySize = round(height/transform[1]);

    //create the new (cropped) dataset
    pCroppedRaster = pDriver->Create(cropPath, xSize, ySize, 1, GDT_Float32, NULL) //or something similar

    //now all you have to do is find the number of columns and rows the top left corner
    //of the cropped raster if offset from the original raster, and use those values to 
    //read data from the original raster and copy/write the data to the new (cropped) raster
}
```

It should be fairly easy to copy the projection from the input raster to the cropped raster. I usually don't worry about projections when I work in GDAL. However, it is very important to make sure you keep track of the affine transformation data. If your rasters are all in the same projection the affine transformation data will accurately describe their spatial location relative to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can always inspect the GDAL utilities for how they do it. For example, if you just want to "chip out" a section of an image, you could use `gdal_translate -srcwin`.

The simplest way would just be to invoke gdal_translate (e.g. with a `system()` call, or maybe a `CreateProcess()` call if you're on Windows). Otherwise, you'd could read the code for gdal_translate.cpp to extract the bits you need.

If your needs are pretty simple, you can probably just use the [RasterIO](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a75d4af97b3436a4e79d9759eedf89af4) function twice - once to read the data, and again to write the data out. Examples of both are given in the [GDAL API tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from gdal (see other answers) and building a virtual file, you can use the OTB library. This is a C++ open source library including a large set of filters for image processing. Specifically, the [otb::MultiChannelExtractROI](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/doxygen/classotb_1_1MultiChannelExtractROI.html) does the trick. It is also available as an [application](http://otbcb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Applications/app_ExtractROI.html) if you want to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using python and GDAL:

```
    #Atention with -projwin ulx uly lrx lry (upper left (ymax, xmin) - low right (xmax, ymin))
    command = "gdal_translate" + " " \
              "-of GTiff" + " " \
              "-ot Float64 " + \
              "-co compress=LZW " + \
              "-projwin" + " " + \
                    str(xmin) + " " + \
                    str(ymax) + " " + \
                    str(xmax) + " " + \
                    str(ymin) + " " + \
              path_to_raster_tiff + " " + \
              output_path
    os.system(command)
```

Answer (score -1):

http://gis-techniques.blogspot.com/2015/09/clip-raster-with-shapefile-using-c-and.html#.VfiVehFVhHw has example on cropping raster with feature using C# and Gdal. Hope it shed you some ideas to use GDAL with C++ to crop raster with shape.