# Converting GDAL Raster to a Boost Python Array (C++)

Tags: gdal, clip, c++, numpy

My Python project has a C++ extension that accepts detection coordinates to crop a GDAL raster, and then return the crop to the Python side.

On the C++ side, I create a uint8_t buffer to hold the crop. Then I performed RasterIO on my GeoTiff dataset, reading it into the buffer. I then created a NumPy array with the buffer data.

```
class GDAL {

    public:
        GDALDataset* geoTiffDataset;
        GDALDriver* pDriver;
        double geotransform[6];      // 6-element geotranform array.
        int NROWS, NCOLS, NLEVELS;     // dimensions of data in Geotiff.

        GDAL(const char* filename) {
            GDALAllRegister();
            pDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
            geoTiffDataset = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(filename, GA_ReadOnly);
            NROWS = GDALGetRasterYSize(geoTiffDataset);
            NCOLS = GDALGetRasterXSize(geoTiffDataset);
            NLEVELS = GDALGetRasterCount(geoTiffDataset);
            geoTiffDataset->GetGeoTransform(geotransform);
        }

        ~GDAL() {
            GDALClose(geoTiffDataset);
            GDALClose(pDriver);
            GDALDestroyDriverManager();

        }

        ndarray Translate(const char* output_path, int x1, int y1, int width, int height) 
        {
            
            uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*)CPLMalloc(width * height * NLEVELS * sizeof(uint8_t));

            geoTiffDataset->RasterIO(GDALRWFlag::GF_Read, x1, y1, width, height,
                buf, width, height, GDT_Byte, NLEVELS, NULL,
                0, 0, 0);

            py::tuple shape = py::make_tuple(height, width, NLEVELS);
            py::tuple stride = py::make_tuple(width * sizeof(uint8_t),
                * sizeof(uint8_t), sizeof(uint8_t));

            np::dtype dtype = np::dtype::get_builtin<uint8_t>();
            np::ndarray ndImg = np::from_data(buf, dtype, shape, stride, py::object());

            free(buf);
            return ndImg;
        }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(CentroidCorrectExt) {

    Py_Initialize();
    np::initialize();

    py::class_<GDAL, boost::shared_ptr<GDAL>,
        boost::noncopyable>("GDAL", init<const char*>()).
        def("Translate", &GDAL::Translate);
}
```

I then returned the crop to the Python side and displayed it with OpenCV's imshow(). However, it seems like the cropping is incorrect. The returned crop is a colorless image, even though printing array.shape showed that it has 4 channels.

[image]

What the crop should look like (4 color channels).

[image]

Is this a problem caused by how I called RasterIO()? Or is the NumPy array shape or stride that I initialized is incorrect?

Comment: hmmm.. Rasterio has a [page](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html) about not using rasterio and gdal together, sicne they both use conflicting dynamic libraries. Maybe have a look on [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134349/how-to-crop-geotiff-image-in-c-gdal-or-other-possibilities) that discusses pure C++ options fo cropping.

Comment: Do you mean the Python RasterIO library? I am using RasterIO() that is part of GDALDataset and GDALRasterband in C++. Sorry for the confusion.